# Angular 2: Access object data

Tags: json, object, angular

In my Angular RC2 app I make an observable HTTP call that returns the following JSON to me from the API:

```
{
    "success":true,
    "data":
    {
        "Type": 1
        "Details":{
            "Id":"123",
            "Name":"test",
            "Description":"test"
        }
    }
}
```

I map the data like this:

```
this._myService.get(id)
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.details = data.Details;
            this.type = data.Type;
        },
        (error) => {
            this.setError(error);
        }
     );
```

How do I access the values inside the "Details" object from here?

I tried:

```
{{details.Name}}
```

But that won't work and I can't use ngFor to loop it either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the Elvis operator for this:

```
{{details?.Name}}
```

As a matter of fact, you load your data asynchronously so `details` is undefined at the beginning.

Comment: You could also use `*ngIf="details"` or `*ngIf="details.Name"` (so you could show something like "loading" for `*ngIf="!details"`)

Comment: @bene yes agreed! It depends on the use case ;-)